# Magento 2: Above the fold CSS - inline CSS to <head>

Tags: magento2, css, magento-2.1.4, inline

(Magento 2.1.4) I am trying to add my 'above the fold' CSS in to the `<head>` section.

I know I can add it in via **Content > Configuration > HTML Head** however the issue with this is that it loads it AFTER the merged/minified deployed CSS files.

I've tried just putting `<style>CSS</style>` in to my **default_head_block.xml** but that doesn't work. And as far as I can tell you can't put a block in to this XML (I might be wrong though)

What is the best method?

Thanks

Comment: you cant directly put a style tag in default_head_block, I think the best way is to add your custom css as a separate css file.

Comment: Is there then anyway to move the other CSS files in the head to the bottom of the page? Basically I am try to load my 'above the fold' CSS first to comply with google pagespeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include css file in "default_head_block.xml" file see the example below:

```
<css src="Vendor_Module::css/filename.css"/>
```

Comment: thanks but is there then anyway to move the other CSS files in the head to the bottom of the page? Basically I am try to load my 'above the fold' CSS first to comply with google pagespeed. Thanks